# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMeds') in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, blockchain, solidity

The error comes out when I am trying to addMedicine into React. I tried all sorts of troubleshooting methods like searching up on the forum, but none of it helped.

AddMedicine.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class AddMedicine extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content">
                <p> Total no of medicine {this.props.MedCount} </p>
                <h1>Add Medicine </h1>
                <form onSubmit={(event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    const name = this.name.value
                    const description = this.description.value
                    const dosage = this.dosage.value
                    const company = this.company.value
                    //web3.utils.toWei('1', 'Ether')
                    const price = "1000000000"
                    //const price = window.web3.utils.toWei(this.petPrice.value.toString(), 'Ether')
                    this.props.addMeds(name, description, dosage, company, price);
                }}>
                    <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
                        <input
                            id="Name"
                            type="text"
                            ref={(input) => { this.name = input }}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Medicine Name"
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
                        <input
                            id="Description"
                            type="text"
                            ref={(input) => { this.description = input }}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Description"
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
                        <input
                            id="Dosage"
                            type="text"
                            ref={(input) => { this.dosage = input }}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Medicine Dosage"
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
                        <input
                            id="Company"
                            type="text"
                            ref={(input) => { this.company = input }}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Medicine Company"
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <br />

                    <br />
                    <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
                        <input
                            id="medicinePrice"
                            type="text"
                            ref={(input) => { this.price = input }}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Medicine Price"
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add Medicine</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddMedicine;
```

MedicineContract.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract MedicineContract {
    enum MedStatus {
        Ordered,
        EnRoute,
        Completed,
        Availability
    }

    MedStatus public currentMedStatus;
    uint256 MedCount;
    string companyName;

    constructor() {
        companyName = "Whirlwind's Medicine";
    }

    //Declaring a structure Medicine Details
    struct MedicineDetails {
        uint medicineId;
        string name;
        string description;
        string dosage;
        string company;
        uint price;
        address payable ownerId;
        MedStatus status;
    }
    //Declare an event MedicineCreated
    event MedicineCreated(
        uint id,
        string name,
        string description,
        string dosage,
        string company,
        uint price,
        address owner,
        MedStatus status
    );
    event MedicinePurchased(
        uint id,
        string name,
        uint price,
        address payable owner,
        MedStatus status
    );
    mapping(uint => MedicineDetails) public listOfMedicine;

    //function to add medicine to the Medicine Array
    function addMeds(
        string memory name,
        string memory description,
        string memory dosage,
        string memory company,
        uint price
    ) external {
        require(bytes(name).length > 0);
        require(price > 0);
        MedCount++;
        listOfMedicine[MedCount] = MedicineDetails(
            MedCount,
            name,
            description,
            dosage,
            company,
            price,
            payable(msg.sender),
            MedStatus.Availability
        );
        //Event trigger
        emit MedicineCreated(
            MedCount,
            name,
            description,
            dosage,
            company,
            price,
            payable(msg.sender),
            MedStatus.Availability
        );
    }

    function purchaseMedicine(uint id) public payable {
        //Fetch the product
        MedicineDetails memory medicine = listOfMedicine[id];
        //Fetch the owner
        address payable seller = medicine.ownerId;
        //Make sure the product has a valid ID
        require(medicine.medicineId > 0 && medicine.medicineId <= MedCount);
        //Require that there is enough Ether in the transaction
        require(msg.value >= medicine.price);
        //Require that the product hasn't been purchased
        require(medicine.status == MedStatus.Availability);
        //Require that the buyer is not the seller
        require(seller != msg.sender);
        //Transfer ownership to the buyer
        medicine.ownerId = payable(msg.sender);
        //Mark as purchased
        medicine.status = MedStatus.Completed;
        //Update the product
        listOfMedicine[id] = medicine;
        //Pay the Seller by sending them Ether
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
        //Trigger an event
        emit MedicinePurchased(
            MedCount,
            medicine.name,
            medicine.price,
            payable(msg.sender),
            MedStatus.Completed
        );
    }

    //Getting the company name
    function getCompanyName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return companyName;
    }

    //Getting the number of medicine
    function getMedCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return MedCount;
    }
}
```

App.js

Comment: Can you share how are you passing the props to `<AddMedicine />` component?